# parameters from one page to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

if I have this on one html.erb page

```
<%= text_field("cars_", "name", :size => "30") %>
```

and

```
def find
  @car = Car.new(params[:car_])
  carsearch = @car.name
....
```

why is the carsearch coming as nil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe because the field is `cars_` (plural) and the find is using `car_` (singular)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use `carsearch` on an erb template, then you need to make it an attribute instead of a variable, it should be `@carsearch`.